# spectrum - input value not changing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, spectrum

I try use [spectrum](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) in a form on an input field with id `id_color`.

However, selecting a color does not change the value of `id_color`. What am I doing wrong?

**[edit1]**
Seems like the key to the problem is the option `showButtons: false`. I would rather like the buttons not to be visible...

**[edit2]**
Seems like the combination `showButtons: false` and `flat: true` does not work.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/1855/

If this is important: I use Firefox 25.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Bug...

Opened a ticket for that: https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/issues/202